# I need to write a contract for state synced ETH <> Polygon staking, any advice on how to do this would be very appreciated

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I need to write a contract for state synced ETH <> Polygon(L2) staking. NFTs will need to be staked in return for tokens on Polygon. Where do I even start with this sort of thing, is their documentation or an example somewhere?
Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need your staking contract on L1 to implement [FxbaseRootTunnel](https://github.com/fx-portal/contracts/blob/main/contracts/tunnel/FxBaseRootTunnel.sol) and send messages to L2 via `_sendMessageToChild`. This emits an event which is handled by the Polygon Bridge and executed and sent to your child contract on L2.

Your contract on L2 (either directly the erc20 token or some handler that can mint tokens) needs to implement [FxBaseChildTunnel](https://github.com/fx-portal/contracts/blob/main/contracts/tunnel/FxBaseChildTunnel.sol). Here you need to override `_processMessageFromRoot` and add a `validateSender(sender)` modifier to the function in order to process received messages. Have a look at some of the [examples](https://github.com/fx-portal/contracts/tree/main/contracts/examples/erc20-transfer). Also check out their [deploy scripts](https://github.com/fx-portal/contracts/tree/main/scripts).

After deploying both contracts (L1 & L2), you need to link them via
`rootContract.setFxChildTunnel(address fxChildTunnelL2Address)`
`childContract.setFxRootTunnel(address fxRootTunnelL1Address)`, in order to correctly validate the sender.

Now it depends on how and where you want to do the accounting (L1 or L2). The safe and recommended way (which is more involved and a bit more complicated) is to send a message to L2 saying who staked which id (upon staking) and you basically have the accounting (of balances) on L2. When unstaking you should first confirm a release on L2 and send a message to the root confirming the release. In order for the user to release the NFT on L1, they would need to call `receiveMessage` (only after polygon has confirmed the valid l2 transaction in the merkle tree hash on l1) with a valid 'proof'. There are some ressources on how to create these, but there is also a simpler api for generating the correct proof `inputData`: `` fetch(`https://apis.matic.network/api/v1/mumbai/exit-payload/${txHash}?eventSignature=${eventSig}`) ``

A simpler (less safe, but still pretty good) way is to do the accounting on L1 and only submit events containing changes in staked L1 balances to L2.
This way you only ever "push" messages to L1 and unstaking is a simple call on L1. Assuming no message being sent to L2 ever gets lost you wouldn't have to submit any proof for unstaking. This does bring some security risks though (especially if you only ever send relative balance updates, i.e. +1, -1), make sure you understand these. And you can further mitigate this by "mirroring" staked id ownerships on l2 and double check that one id is only ever allowed to be staked once.

I might release a repository for this soon and give an update here.

Comment: wow thats a comprehensive answer, thankyou so much. Are you available for hire btw? sounds like you could write this pretty quick

Comment: added socials to my profile!

Comment: Checked your socials, twitter, github, personal website and none of them allow me to contact you directly